# Yii2 Почему pjax перезагружает страницу при удалении (ActionColumn)?

Tags: yii2, gridview, pjax

Страница перезагружается при нажатии из ActionColumn (иконке delete):

```
<div class="tab-pane fade scot-form-index" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
    <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'comments', 'enablePushState' => false, 'linkSelector' => '.btn-custom', 'clientOptions'=> ['method'=>'POST']]); ?>
    <?=
        Html::a('<span class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Добавить данные', ['animal/create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']).'<br>'
    ?>
    <div class="report-index card border-primary">
        <table>
            <?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'layout'=>"<div class='bg-j'><span style='text-align:right; padding-bottom: 10px; position:absolute;'>{pager}</span><span style='text-align:right; padding-bottom: 10px;' >{summary}</span></div>\n{items}\n{pager}",
                'tableOptions' => [
                    'class' => 'table tableusers table-striped table-bordered table-warp'
                ],
                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'table-responsive',
                ],
                'pager' => [
                    'options'=>['class'=>'pagination'],
                    'maxButtonCount'=>10,
                ],
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
                        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;', 'class'=>'jus'],
                        'header' => '№',
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => name',
                        'label' => 'Продукты',
                        'contentOptions'  => ['style' => 'text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;', 'class'=>'jus'],
                        'headerOptions'   => ['class' => 'text-center']
                    ],                      
                    [   'attribute' => 'Дата',
                        'label' => 'Дата',
                        'attribute' => 'date',
                        'format' => ['DateTime', 'php:d.m.Y H:i:s'],                            
                        'contentOptions'  => ['style' => 'text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;', 'class'=>'jus'],
                        'headerOptions'   => ['class' => 'text-center']
                    ],
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                        'template' => "{view}\n{update}\n{delete}",
                        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; width: 100px;'],
                        'headerOptions'   => ['class' => 'text-center'],
                        'buttons' => [
                            'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                                Icon::map($this, Icon::FAS);
                                return Html::a('<span class="fas fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></span>', $url);
                            },
                            'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                                return Html::a('<span class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>', $url);
                            },
                            'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                                return Html::a('<span class="fas fa-trash btn-custom" aria-hidden="true"></span>', $url, [
                                    'data-method' => 'post',
                                    'data-pjax' => '1',
                                ]);
                            }

                        ],
                        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                            if ($action === 'view') {
                                $url = Url::to(['animal/view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                                //$url = 'index.php?r=animal/view&id=' . $model->id;
                                return $url;
                            }
                            if ($action === 'update') {
                                $url = Url::to(['animal/update', 'id' => $model->id]);
                                //$url = 'index.php?r=animal/update&id=' . $model->id;
                                return $url;
                            }
                            if ($action === 'delete') {
                                $url = Url::to(['animal/delete', 'id' => $model->id ]);
                                //$url = 'index.php?r=animal/delete&id=' . $model->id;
                                return $url;
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                ],

            ]);
            ?>
        </table>
        <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
    </div>
```

контроллер(все что связано с delete)

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                // 'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    }
    return $this->redirect(['post/animal']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перезагружает, потому что actionDelete() возвращает редирект:

```js
return $this->redirect(['post/animal']);
```

Если хочешь чтобы работало без перезагрузки, нужно переделать actionDelete() чтобы возвращал то же самое что и actionIndex():

```js
return $this->render('index', [
    'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```